# Is there an equivallent in Kotlin to the '+=' Operator on TextViews?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: I want to keep the text in the text view and add 0 to it]
I have tried txtCalc.text = "The text" + "0" and it doesn't work

Comment: You might want to look at android data binding if you want to actually use modifiable view strings

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you read the current text in the `TextView`, you'll get a `CharSequence`, which you'll have to turn into a string before concatenating anything to it:

```
textView.text = textView.text.toString() + "0"
```

Or you can just use the [`append`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) method of `TextView`:

```
textView.append("0")
```

---

Or if you literally want to use `+=`, you can create your own extension on `TextView`:

```
inline operator fun TextView.plusAssign(text: CharSequence) = append(text)

textView += "0"
```

Comment: thanks i have used textView.append("0") it's good 
but how about if i want to add 0 before the old text Like 
textView.text = "0" + textView.text

Comment: You can still use the first code example I've shown you - either as is, or with string templates as shown in the other answer by @Willi Mentzel

Answer (score 0):

A CharSequence, which `text` is, does not define the `+` (plus operator).

Using a string template you can write it more concise anyway.

Note:`toString()` is called implicitly on text (`CharSequence`) which turns it into a `String`.

```
textView.text = "${textView.text}0"
```

Comment: Not Working Still the same Error  
https://image.ibb.co/eAx46d/Screenshot_from_2018_07_01_15_58_34.png